# how to create a grid/matrix in sas?

Tags: sas

Basically I have this

```
proc means data=mydada1;
    var variable1;
run;
proc means data=mydada2;
    var variable2;
run;
```

I have like 14 of these proc means they basically calculate the mean marl for each data set.
I want to display these means in 2x2 grid or matrix something like below

```
     HistoryMark  GeographyMark MathematicsMarks 
Name   
John  2.2         2.5         2.6
Jack  2.7         2.8          9.0
```

I was thinking of 2D array but I don't know how to extract the data from the proc means and also is there anyway of getting rid of these 14 proc means and creating one step that calculates the means of various data set.

Mydata,MyData1 looks something like this

```
2.3 
2.5
2.78 
2.9
-2.4
-2.5
2.09
2.9999
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stack all of the data in one dataset with a variable that indicates which dataset it comes from (in this case, it looks like it would contain 'HistoryMark' etc.).  Then you can use `PROC MEANS` with a `CLASS` statement, or in your case perhaps better is `PROC TABULATE` with `CLASS`.  Assuming `have` is the datset created from stacking your datasets together:

```
proc tabulate data=have;
class name mark_class;
var mark;
tables name,mark_class*mark*mean;
run;
```

Something like that, assuming you have `mark` (their score), `name` (their name), and `mark_class` (the class the mark is for).

Comment: sorry I am bit a confused how would I combine all the results from the proc means into one data set.

Comment: No, combine the datasets _before_ the `proc means`.  Construct a dataset with one row for each row in your original dataset, with `mark` (the score for that class), `mark_class` (the class they got that mark in), and `name` (the student's name).  The variable names can be anything, these are just placeholders for the example.

Comment: Thats a good idea the issue with that is, the data is range of marks and some datasets my have more marks then the others.

Comment: How is this relevant?  Mean is mean, isn't it, regardless of the range?  The `class` statement sets things up so that they are basically independent calculations, one for each column, so the different class values don't affect each other really.

Comment: In any event, you could actually do this on the post-proc means data as well; take each of the proc means output datasets, set them together with a variable indicating which one (`mark_class` still), and the tabulate is still the same (mean of 1 value = the value).

Comment: I did what you said I combined the data sets before calculating the means thanks mate really appreciate the help.